# mysql query getting all fields in table 1 and partial in from table two

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Coming back to my very old mysql skills I have need of the following query.

I have two tables

One is a table of all items called products with cols item name, item num

Two is a table of purchased items with cols item num, date

What I need as a result is something like this

```
ITEM-----PURCHASED
item1-------0 
item2-------0
item3-------0
item4-------1  This item purchased
item5-------0
item6-------1  This item purchased
item7-------0
item8-------0
.
.
.
itemX-------0
```

Output contains all items and a 1 in the purchased col if the item exist in the purchased items table
and a 0 if it has NOT been purchased.

I am sorry if this is easy my brain is in meltdown mode currently and it has been a long time I have needed something like this

Answer (score 4):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` and a `CASE` to test for `NULL` in the joined table, you can return a zero or 1 accordingly (I used `CASE` but you could also do `IFNULL()` in MySQL):

```
SELECT
  products.name, 
  products.item_num
  /* items that have no related rows in `purchased` will be NULL */
  CASE WHEN purchased.item_num IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END AS purchased
  /* Could also just do:
       (purchesd.item_num IS NULL) AS purchased
     because MySQL will return a 0 or 1 from the boolean condition, 
     but the CASE is more portable */
FROM 
  products
  LEFT JOIN purchased ON products.item_num = purchased.item_num
```